# istream and ostream across platforms

Tags: c++, portability, iostream, endianness

Suppose I would want to write this on my big-endian machine

```
an_ostream_impl my_output_on_BE;
my_output_on_BE << __int32(0x1234);
```

And this on my little-endian machine

```
an_istream_impl my_input_on_LE;  

__int32 value;
my_input_on_LE >> value;
assert( value == 0x1234 );
```

Is there an istream/ostream implementation allowing this?  E.g. that always streams numbers in Big Endian (or whatever format)?

Comment: I assume you are using streams in binary mode?

Comment: @BjörnPollex: yes, and they are to be initialized properly by someone who knows what byte order is used internally.  I'm hoping for something as simple as `cout.setflags(std::big_endian)`.

Comment: All implementations should support this as the default implementation of `operator<<` outputs the textual representation of the value and `operator>>` parses the textual representation of the value. It does not matter if the stream is in binary mode or not, non-binary mode only affect '\n'.

Comment: @dalle: indeed - you're right.  I shouldn't have written the receiver part in terms of stream insertion.  It's a network protocol I'm trying to represent, and the receiver is out of my control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any implementation that is capable of this out-of-the-box. The easiest way to write something like this yourself is probably by using [Boost.Iostreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/doc/index.html). You could simply implement [devices](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/doc/concepts/device.html) for the appropriate conversions, and then use [`stream`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iostreams/doc/guide/generic_streams.html#stream) to create a stream that delegates to the device you have written and exposes a standard `iostream` interface.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to share data more complicated than a single integer between machines I'd heartily recommend [Google Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/). You define "messages" in a text file, run them through a compiler (protoc) and get source in your language of choice. This source defines objects corresponding to your message specifications plus serialisation and deserialisation methods.

Comment: Looked like what I needed - but... can I use this _without_ the tags?  In other words: Can I 'reverse engineer' an existing protocol into a Protocol Buffer message?

Answer (score 0):

In that case the only way is probably to serialize/deserialize yourself i.e. reading/writing byte by byte.